# Now that I've posted content to my my PHP script, how do I fetch it?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post, xmlhttprequest

I've posted content with the following code:

```
function checkphp() {
    var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xml.open("POST", 'testphp.php');
    xml.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xml.send('alame=Henry');
    xml.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xml.readyState == 4 && xml.status == 200) {
            document.body.innerHTML = xml.responseText;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried this:

```
echo($_POST['alame']) or die("Nothing was posted");
```

But it doesn't work... it spits out '1'. any suguestions?

Comment: Define 'doesn't work'. Does anything happen? Do you get an error message? Have you checked the server logs? Is there a pertinent message there?

Comment: If your testphp.php is a good script, the calling html document should show this content "Henry".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem that cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting `1` because PHP is echo'ing the value of ($_POST['alname'])(`true`) OR die;

```
$someVar = 'test';
$someBool = false;

$a = ($someVar) || die();
echo $a; // 1
var_dump($a); //bool(true)

$a = ($someBool) || die(); // dies
```

In languages such as JavaScript, you might expect a different behavior:

```
// In JS
var someVal = false;
var somethingElse = someVal || "fallback";
console.log(somethingElse); // "fallback"
```

In PHP, however, the whole expression is evaluated, so

```
// In PHP
$someVal = false;
$somethingElse = $someVal || "fallback";
echo $somethingElse; // 1
```

`$someVal || "fallback"` evaluated to true, because PHP boiled them down to `(false || true) => true`

@jacouh is wrong that it's unpredictable to get `1`, but quite correct that you should check for your variables in a different way, such as the ternary or some similar method, e.g.

```
if(!isset($_POST['alame']))
    die("Noting was posted");

// Continue and do something with $_POST['alame'];
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested you script, we can see you message with a testphp.php like this:

```
<?php
//
//var_dump($_POST);
//echo($_POST['alame']) or die("Nothing was posted");
//
echo $_POST['alame'];
?>
```

"Henry" will be shown in the document body as expected.

With this:

```
echo($_POST['alame']) or die("Nothing was posted");
```

1 is returned.

echo is used here as function, but it cannot be, see http://fr.php.net/echo :

> echo is not actually a function (it is a language construct), so you
>   are not required to use parentheses with it. echo (unlike some other
>   language constructs) does not behave like a function, so it cannot
>   always be used in the context of a function.

So 1 is an unpredictable result in this context, I've no explanation.

Or you might use this:

```
echo isset($_POST['alame']) ? $_POST['alame'] : "Nothing was posted";
```

Comment: My guess as to why the `echo()` returned 1 would be that the passed statement was evaluated to a Boolean - `echo(true OR die());` would give a true (1) return.

Comment: but PHP::echo does not return any thing, please test $i = echo("This is bad."); error occurs. the value 1 is still a mystery.

Comment: +1 also b/c you mentioned that indeed echo is not a function - it's being "treated" like one with the syntax, but in reality the ($_POST['alame']) is just on it's own - `echo    ('something');` still  echos 'something' because the ( and ) don't matter in this context to PHP, other than as separators as they would be in arithmetic - `echo (4/2)+3; // 5`